# Walk to the corner and turn left

Tags: word-choice

I wonder if there's another way to answer this question:

> Excuse me. Where is the post office?

> Just walk to the corner and turn left.

Can we say:

> It's around the corner on the left.

Do they have the same meaning?

Comment: How is your suggested sentence any "easier" than the first sentence? And, no, they don't mean the same thing.

Comment: @AlanCarmack: "_How is your suggested sentence any "easier" than the first sentence?_" Corrected. "_they don't mean the same thing._" Would you mind explaining the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meanings are different.

> Just walk to the corner and turn left.

This specifies which way to turn when you reach the corner, but does not specify which side of the road the post office is on once you have turned the corner.

> It's around the corner on the left.

This doesn't tell you which direction to turn, but does specify which side of the road the post office will be on once you have turned the corner.

You could combine these two pieces of information like this:

> Turn left at the corner: the post office is on the left.